# Как правильно реализовывать логику выбора данных из кэша или из сети?

Tags: android, архитектура

А как правильно реализовывать логику выбора данных из кэша или из сети? Что если иногда надо брать из кэша, а иногда из сети? Правильно ли делать в репозиторие методы типо `getFromnetwork` и `getFromcache`? Например, в случае если пулл-ту-рефреш, то это обязательно из сети, а в каких-то других случаях можно и из кэша взять. Или например, есть ситуация: есть обьект, мне сначала нужно сделать бизнес-операцию над ним, далее показать, паралельно отправить запрос в облако, для обновления данных об обьекте, и когда запрос выполнится, отобразить актуалные данные из сети. По сути мне нужно знать об существовании разных источников данных на уровне бизнес логики. Тогда какая часть должна быть в репозиторие?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Логика получения данных, в общем случае, хранится в специальном классе на уровне модели.

Далее возможны 2 подхода:

1) Решение происходит в менеджере источников данных, находящемся в имплементации репозитория.

В случае, когда бизнес логике просто нужно получить данные, неважно, закешированные, или непосредственно от сервера,  Менеджер источников данных (например, `SmthDataStoreFactory`) внедряется в `SmthRepository` и сам решает, как вытаскивать данные - из сети или кеша. Примером такой логики может быть задание срока, в течение которого закешированные данные считаются актуальными. Данный подход применяется в [демо проекте Fernando Cejas.](https://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/)

Второй подвариант - менеджер всегда возвращает данные из кешированного источника, если они есть, а потом всё равно делает запрос на сервер, возвращая обновлённые данные. Затем, обновлённые данные перезаписывают закешированные.

2) В случае, когда бизнес логике важно, чтобы данные пришли свежими, отправляется специальный флаг вроде `needFreshData`, его получает менеджер и понимает, что кэш в данном случае не подходит и делает запрос на сервер. Если нужна более гибкая настройка, можно использовать различные стратегии для выборки данных, `FirstCache`, `NoCache` и т.д. В таком случае, в репозитории будут методы с сигнатурой,  `getUser(int id, boolean needFreshData)` или `getUser(int id, CachePolicy policy)` и интеракторы явно вызывают тот или иной метод.

Примеры обоих подходов:

1) Необходимо получить профиль пользователя - обычно, нам достаточно и закешированных данных, нет необходимости в явном указании источника данных.

2) Необходимо получить текущий баланс банковской карты после совершения платежа - тут мы явно указываем, что данные нужны "самые свежие"